# Proximity Service minimum radius

Tags: android, proximity

I have developed an App that with proximity Service should detect when I enter in a radius of "x" meters from given gps coordinate and start a timer.
But sometimes the timer start much farther the radius set.
By far I mean that I setted 80 meters for radius:

```
private static final float POINT_RADIUS = 80;


PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, unique_id, intentNew, 0);
        lm.addProximityAlert(latitude, longitude, POINT_RADIUS, -1, pi);
```

And something when I'am at 200 meters the timer start.
So I would like to ask a question,
What is the minimium radius to limit the proximity errors?
80 meters is too short to have an accuracy?